# Temperature converter program in C is not working . Stops after executing some code (run time error)

Tags: c

I have written a C program which converts temperature from fahrenheit to celcius. It has three functions , input_temp() , input_unit() and calculate() . Idea is simple . input_temp() asks the user to enter the value of temperature . input_unit() asks the user to enter the unit i.e. F for fahrenheit and C for celcius . Calculate() converts the temperature based on the units (celcius to fahrenheit or fahrenheit to celcius) . I am using Code::Blocks as my IDE , But whenever I tried to run this program , Code::Blocks stopes working after asking the unit of numerical temperature . When I tried to run the same code in ideone.com , it says Runtime error . Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

calculate(float T , char U[]);

int main()
{
    float temp ;
    char unit[5] ;
    float ans ;

    temp = input_temp() ;

    strcpy(unit, input_unit()) ;

    ans = calculate(temp , unit) ;

    printf("Converted temperature is %f ." , ans);

    return 0;
}

int input_temp()
{
    float x ;

    printf("Enter the temperature : ") ;
    scanf("%f" , &x ) ;
    return x ;
}

input_unit()
{
    char Unit[5] ;
    printf("Enter the unit (C or F) : ") ;
    scanf("%s" , Unit) ;
    return Unit ;
}

calculate(float T , char U[])
{
    float convert ;
    if (strcmp(U , 'F') == 0)
    {
        convert = (T-32)*5/9 ;
    }
    else  // if(strcmp(U , 'C') == 0)
    {
        convert = (T*9/5)+32 ;
    }
    return convert ;
}
```

I believe I made some mistake in Calculate() function (But I am not sure) . Please help me to figure it out . And how to determine Runtime Error?

Comment: You haven't added function prototypes of all the functions before the beginning of the main()!!! Edit return type of input_unit() as a `char*`!!! There are several errors.

Comment: Your compiler surely raised some warnings about this code. What are they?

Answer (score 0):

```
strcmp(U , 'F')
```

is wrong. You need

```
strcmp(U , "F")
```

`strcmp` takes char arrays not chars. 'F' becomes the integer value of char 'F' - for eg. in ASCII it's 70. So `strcmp` looks for a char array starting at address 70.

Comment: Thanks for your help , working :) . But it is giving only interger values . Eg :- 10 F in digree celcius is -12.000000 , Why it is not giving -12.2222 .

Comment: Because 5/9 will be calculated as a constant at compile time, using integer math. You can do 5.0/9 or use a decimal constant.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to store the required units in any more than a `char`. With some other cleaning up:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

float calculate(float T , char unit);
float input_temp();
char input_unit();

int main()
{
    float temp ;
    char unit;
    float ans ;

    temp = input_temp();
    unit = input_unit();
    ans = calculate(temp ,unit);

    printf("Converted temperature is %f.\n" , ans);
    return 0;
}

float input_temp()
{
    float x ;

    printf("Enter the temperature : ") ;
    scanf("%f" , &x ) ;
    return x ;
}

char input_unit()
{
    char U[5];
    printf("Enter the unit (C or F) : ") ;
    scanf("%s" , U) ;
    if (strcmp(U, "F") == 0) {
        return 'F';
    }
    return 'C' ;
}

float calculate(float T , char U)
{
    float convert ;
    if (U == 'F')
    {
        convert = (T-32)*5./9 ;
    }
    else
    {
        convert = (T*9./5)+32 ;
    }
    return convert ;
}
```